# How to directly read the value of the `std::atomic_int64_t` without atomic operation?

Tags: c++

I have an `std::atomic_int64_t` that can be read by multiple threads but written by only one thread. In the one thread that writes the atomic, I want to read it directly without any atomic-related instruction since there won't be concurrent writing. How should I do that in C++?

Comment: It doesn't matter if there will be concurrent writing. If there can be concurrent reads and writes you still need to be atomic. Besides, why bother? Unless it's a *very* hot path that's *extremely* performance critical,then you are unlikely to ever notice any difference.

Comment: As an alternative to atomics, you could consider having the readers use [`std::shared_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) and the writer use [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) so the readers can be concurrent but the writer must be exclusive

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is a part of an interview task that requires the solution as optimized as possible. In this case, for the read of the only thread that writes, what memory order should I use?

Comment: _"How should I do that in C++?"_ you can't. _"This is a part of an interview task that requires the solution as optimized as possible"_ without context, it's a terrible question.

Comment: Any time the writer writes to the public `std::atomic_int64_t` it should also write the new value to a private `std::int64_t` that it can use as a read cache.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Another option is to compile and run your code on a machine where `std::atomic_int64_t{}.is_lock_free() == true`.

Comment: "requires the solution as optimized as possible" is a terrible metric. You can quite easily spend [more time optimising](https://xkcd.com/1205/) than the code will ever take being run

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure without knowing your use case if what you're trying to do is reasonable, but there's about a 99.95% chance that it's a bad idea. The reason for this is not obvious, so let me have a go.

## Complex runtime environments

Atomics, despite the name, are not just about atomic access to a variable, they're about ordering of effects. To understand what this means, we have to understand a little bit about two things:

1. modern CPUs, caches, and memory
2. compiler optimizations

For point 1, consider that a modern CPU consists mostly of memory management. Very little silicon is actually devoted to calculating, most of it is concerned with keeping the calculation units fed with data. When you store a value into memory, chances are it's not going to show up in main memory immediately, instead it'll go to the active CPU core's store buffer that's going to be flushed out at some point in the future, at which point it may become visible to the other CPU core on which your other thread runs. In the name of performance, we have turned our CPUs into highly asynchronous beasts.

For point 2, consider that your compiler will take apart the code you give it, analyze it for data dependencies, and reorder your instructions in such a way that they'll have the same results but run faster. Consider that the compiler can only do this for the code of one thread at a time. It cannot know that another thread depends on what the first one is doing being done in a particular order (or indeed at all), and so it'll run roughshod over the assumptions of that other, unknown thread. Another thread will change a variable, so that'll need to be re-read from time to time? Well, the compiler doesn't know that and has the value in a register, so it'll generate an endless loop and call it a day. This sort of behaviour needs to be inhibited when you have multiple threads.

## Atomics are about synchronization

**The main point of atomics is synchronization**. An Atomic write ensures that store buffers are flushed, things become visible in main memory, and prevent the compiler from reordering instructions across it (possibly one-way, depending on the precise boundary used). Similarly, an atomic read ensures that the values from main memory become visible in cache and prevent the compiler from reordering across it.

So if your reader threads don't use atomic reads, we have a situation: The writer threads does a proper atomic store. This ensures that the compiler does not reorder operations in the writer thread across the atomic boundary, and the generated code ensures that the CPU core's store buffer is flushed. If the reader threads read the atomic variable with an atomic read and see the new value, they'll also see everything else the writer thread was instructed to do up to that point.

So, if the reader does not use an atomic read to read the atomic variable, what could go wrong? Well, basically two things:

1. the cpu core might not see the need to update its cache
2. the compiler could reorder operations across the non-atomic read, or not see a need to re-read a value from memory that the optimizer thought it already knew and had in a register.

In effect, what this means is that the reader thread might work under the assumption that things the writer thread did before the write have already happened, but it ends up "not seeing" those new data. Hilarity will (almost) inevitably ensue.

## TL;DR

Atomics are about synchonisation. You have multiple threads that you need to synchronize. Use atomic reads in the reader thread, or you're not synchronizing.